# Python Pillow Image.show() Path Issue?

Tags: python, image, path, python-imaging-library

Honest warning—I'm a total beginner.

I'm using Python 3.8.2 in IDLE and sometimes in Spyder.

My goal: to open an image **(located in a folder)** in Preview using Pillow

My code:

```
from PIL import Image
my_image = Image.open("flower.jpg")
my_image.show(r"/Users/User/Desktop/flower.jpg")
```

I run this, and it works! **But it only works if the jpg is on the Desktop.** I want to put the image in a folder. So I changed my last line of code to something like this:

```
my_image.show(r"/Users/User/Desktop/folder/flower.jpg")
```

I put the image in the folder, run the program, and get this error:

```
**FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'flower.jpg'**
```

Oddly, if I put the jpg back onto the Desktop and still use the path with "folder" in it, the program runs successfully and shows me the image.

Is this a problem with the path? How can I use Image.show() to open an image that is located somewhere other than the Desktop?

Thank you!

Comment: Check this https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.open to know how to correctly set path in `open`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open and view an image using an absolute path, you'll have to change this line:

```
my_image = Image.open(path_to_image_dir)
```

You've incorrectly passed a string to `PIL.Image.show`. This doesn't throw an error, since `PIL.Image.show` happens to take an optional string parameter `title`, which it will use as a title in the image window. Don't pass any parameters to `show`, and change `"flower.jpg"` in the line above to the actual path.